# How to call a server side method on losing focus from a textbox, asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two textboxes, one isfor 'program' and the other for 'description'. I have a predefined set of programs and it is associated descriptions in the database.

Example : For program named 'Test' it has the description as 'Valid' in the DB Table

For example, when enter a program name in the program textbox as 'Test', its associated 
description 'Valid' should be populated automatically to the 'Description' TextBox on losing focus from the 'Program' TextBox.

How can I achieve this using asp.net mvc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A combination of the textbox blur event and using an ajax call.

```
$('#program').blur( function(){

   //make ajax call to action method to get the description for this value
   $.get(yourActionUrl, { data : $(this).val() }, function(response) {

      //set the value of description text box
      $('#description').val( response );

   });

});
```